# iOS: Collision Objects & PanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, collision-detection, uipangesturerecognizer

I have implemented the `PanGetsureRecognizer` for dragging my `buttons`, `images` and other components on my iPhone screen, but now I have a new conflict concerning the Objects Collision.

I have implemented my need in that way:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(menu1Drag.frame, menu2Drag.frame)){
    // blablabla
}
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. I am wondering if there are specific statements for collision objects with `PanGesture`. I have took a look on many sites, but they are using the same statements like above.
Any ideas?

Comment: Search and investigate more code on github

Comment: No one else? With helpful advices?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether menu1Drag and menu2Drag is in the same level of view hierachy.
2. Try out log the detail of their frame before if(CGRectIntersectsRect(menu1Drag.frame, menu2Drag.frame)).